# Pandas - use pivot_table to convert each unique element in 1 column into a unique column

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to expand a dataframe such that for all the unique elements in the rows of one column, each value becomes a column in its own right.

I start with a dataframe that looks like this.

```
     Colour Age    Type  Count
0    Black  11yrs  Cats  22
1    Black  12yrs  Cats  2
2    White  8yrs   Dogs  10
3    Brown  11yrs  Dogs  2
4    White  12yrs  Cats  14
```

I would like to change the dataframe, such that the columns are the unique elements of Colour column, Black, White, Brown - so that it looks like this:

```
    Age    Type   Black  White Brown 
0   11yrs  Cats   22     0     0   
1   12yrs  Cats   2      14     0
2   8yrs  Dogs    0      10    0
3   11yrs  Dogs   0      0     2
```

I've [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) a few approaches but clearly I am missing something.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `pivot_table` as follows:

```
(df.pivot_table(index=['Age', 'Type'], 
                columns='Colour', 
                values='Count', 
                fill_value=0).reset_index())

Out[22]:
Colour    Age  Type  Black  Brown  White
0       11yrs  Cats     22      0      0
1       11yrs  Dogs      0      2      0
2       12yrs  Cats      2      0     14
3        8yrs  Dogs      0      0     10
```

---

Or `set_index` and `unstack`

```
(df.set_index(['Age', 'Type', 'Colour']).Count.unstack(fill_value=0)
   .reset_index())

Out[23]:
Colour    Age  Type  Black  Brown  White
0       11yrs  Cats     22      0      0
1       11yrs  Dogs      0      2      0
2       12yrs  Cats      2      0     14
3        8yrs  Dogs      0      0     10
```